Can i run .Net 8 runtime on CentOS?
I want to deploy a .net core app with .net 8 on a linux VPS that is running CentOS V7.9. I can't find any way to install .net 8 runtime.
Is there any other way of hosting a .net 8 app on that kind of server or a way to install the necessary runtime?
Also am I missing something in my way of going about it?

CentOS 7 is not supported, as per: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-rhel#where-is-centos-linux , reached end of support June 30, 2024: https://blog.centos.org/2023/04/end-dates-are-coming-for-centos-stream-8-and-centos-linux-7/

Did you try installing the dotnet-runtime-8.0 package?

Have you referred to this document? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux  And I also found this section which mentioned .NET is no longer supported on CentOS Linux. As of June 30th, 2024, CentOS Linux reached end-of-life. For more information, see End dates are coming for CentOS Stream 8 and CentOS Linux 7

@Charlieface Yes i tried running sudo yum install -y dotnet-runtime-8.0 and got
No package dotnet-runtime-8.0 available. Error: Nothing to do

Could you please help check whether you could install .Net 6 or not? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-rhel#rhel-7--net-8  I'm afraid only .net 6 will work in your machine.

@TinyWang Yes, I have seen the doc. But I wanted to see if I was missing something or if someone could tell me if there is a way to install it.
Thank you for the answer.

@TinyWang I installed .net 7 runtime. It seems .net 8 is the problem. I assume if .net 7 could be installed so can .net 6.

yes, I'm also afraid that .Net 8 is not supported in your machine. Since .Net 7 is end-of-life now, so that I asked you to try .Net 6.

Seems a matter of finding a package source that has it in, or downloading it manually and installing.
